# Backslashes after each code block example when answering

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-text

I'm seeing useless backslashes when answering a question and displaying the Markdown help.

### Reproduce the bug:

1. Answer to this question
2. Click on the "?" button ("Markdown editing help")
3. Click on any title ("Links", "Lists", etc.)
4. See misleading `"` at the end of each code block

### See an example:

[image: Misleading backslashes]

(use [*Freehand Circles*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)™ technology with permission)

Problem appears on meta Stack Overflow and StackOverflow with Chrome 25.0.1364.172 and Firefox 25.0, both on Windows XP.

Comment: Reproducible on both MSO and SO: Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m, Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: It's a problem in the HTML source, so it should be visible on all platforms and browsers. I certainly see it in Chrome on Mac OS X.

Comment: For easy access to the help source, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/markdown-help; I see 13 instances of `\</pre>` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already fixed on meta:

[image]

Rolling out to sites in build rev `2013.11.13.1151`